# Passing arguments to rest api call using post in python

Tags: rest, post, python-2.7, argument-passing, atlassian-crucible

I am calling a rest service to "GET" an auth token from login and then pass the same to POST request along with some other data.
The code snippet is

```
issue = json.loads(r4)
print json.dumps(issue, sort_keys=True, indent=4)
data=issue['token']
args=urllib.urlencode({'FEAUTH':data}).replace("%3A", ":")
print "args is", args
args1={'FEAUTH':data}
print "###################################################################"

data = json.dumps({
  "reviewData" : {
    "projectKey" : "EEU",
    "name" : "Example review.",
    "description" : "Test Description",
    "author" : {
      "userName" : "testUser",
      "displayName" : "test user",
      "avatarUrl" : "https://fisheye/avatar/testUser?s=48"
    },
    "moderator" : {
      "userName" : "testUser",
      "displayName" : "test user",
      "avatarUrl" : "https://fisheye/avatar/testUser?s=48"
    },
    "creator" : {
      "userName" : "testUser",
      "displayName" : "test user",
      "avatarUrl" : "https://fisheye/avatar/testUser?s=48"
    },
    "permaId" : {
      "id" : "EEU-598"
    },
    "permaIdHistory" : [ "EEU-597" ],
    "type" : "REVIEW",
    "allowReviewersToJoin" : "false",
    "metricsVersion" : "2",
    "createDate" : "2013-03-11T15:38:54.046+1100",
    "dueDate" : "2013-03-12T15:38:54.046+1100",
    "jiraIssueKey" : ""
  }
})
data1 = (data)
args2={}
**req = conn.request("post","/rest-service/reviews-v1"+"?"+ args, data1, headers) 
r3 = conn.getresponse()** 
status = r3.status
print "the url is"#, r3.getheader('Location')
url=r3.getheader('location', '')
print url
url1=r3.msg.dict#['location']
print url1
print "read"
r4=r3.read()
issue = json.loads(r4)
print json.dumps(issue, sort_keys=True, indent=4)
```

When trying to call the post request the args contains the feauth and data1 has the json object to be passed, the headers has application/json and when calling this I get following error message

args is FEAUTH=user:14254:894b8aaf8c6e455c3c6dde4215e3657d

#

the url is

{'x-ausername': 'anonymous', 'transfer-encoding': 'chunked', 'set-cookie': 'FESESSIONID=1er2ophgu5kqntjbm67nksztc;Path=/;HttpOnly', 'expires': 'Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:00 GMT', 'server': 'Jetty(6.1.26)', 'connection': 'close', 'dat

e': 'Mon, 11 Mar 2013 06:02:12 GMT', 'content-type': 'application/json'}

read

{

"code": "WebApplication",

"message": "com.sun.jersey.api.MessageException: A message body reader for Java class com.atlassian.fecrurestplugin.crucible.RestReviewService$CreateReview, and Java type class com.atlassian.fecrurestplugin.crucible.RestReview

Service$CreateReview, and MIME media type application/octet-stream was not found.\nThe registered message body readers compatible with the MIME media type are:\n*/* ->\n com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FormProvider\n co

m.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StringProvider\n com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ByteArrayProvider\n com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FileProvider\n com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.InputStreamPr

ovider\n com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DataSourceProvider\n com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLJAXBElementProvider$General\n com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ReaderProvider\n com.sun.jersey.core.imp

l.provider.entity.DocumentProvider\n com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$StreamSourceReader\n com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$SAXSourceReader\n com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entit

y.SourceProvider$DOMSourceReader\n com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONJAXBElementProvider$General\n com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootElementProvider$General\n com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XM

LListElementProvider$General\n com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootObjectProvider$General\n com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.EntityHolderReader\n com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONRootElementProvi

der$General\n com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONListElementProvider$General\n com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JacksonProviderProxy\napplication/octet-stream ->\n com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.Byte

ArrayProvider\n com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FileProvider\n com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.InputStreamProvider\n com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DataSourceProvider\n com.sun.jersey.core.impl.prov

ider.entity.RenderedImageProvider\n",

"stacktrace": "javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: com.sun.jersey.api.MessageException: A message body reader for Java class com.atlassian.fecrurestplugin.crucible.RestReviewService$CreateReview, and Java type class com.atlas

sian.fecrurestplugin.crucible.RestReviewService$CreateReview, and MIME media type application/octet-stream was not found.\nThe registered message body readers compatible with the MIME media type are:\n*/* ->\n com.sun.jersey.core

.impl.provider.entity.FormProvider\n com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StringProvider\n com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ByteArrayProvider\n com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FileProvider\n com.sun.jersey

.core.impl.provider.entity.InputStreamProvider\n com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DataSourceProvider\n com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLJAXBElementProvider$General\n com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.R

eaderProvider\n com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DocumentProvider\n com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$StreamSourceReader\n com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$SAXSourceReader\n

com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$DOMSourceReader\n com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONJAXBElementProvider$General\n com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootElementProvider$General\n com

.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLListElementProvider$General\n com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootObjectProvider$General\n com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.EntityHolderReader\n com.sun.jersey.json.i

mpl.provider.entity.JSONRootElementProvider$General\n com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONListElementProvider$General\n com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JacksonProviderProxy\napplication/octet-stream ->\n com.s

un.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ByteArrayProvider\n com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FileProvider\n com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.InputStreamProvider\n com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DataSourceP

rovider\n com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.RenderedImageProvider\n\n\tat com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequest.getEntity(ContainerRequest.java:461)\n\tat com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.EntityPara

mDispatchProvider$EntityInjectable.getValue(EntityParamDispatchProvider.java:123)\n\tat com.sun.jersey.server.impl.inject.InjectableValuesProvider.getInjectableValues(InjectableValuesProvider.java:46)\n\tat com.atlassian.plugins.r

est.common.interceptor.impl.DispatchProviderHelper$EntityParamInInvoker.getParams(DispatchProviderHelper.java:127)\n\tat com.atlassian.plugins.rest.common.interceptor.impl.DispatchProviderHelper$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(Dispat

chProviderHelper.java:196)\n\tat com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)\n\tat com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMet

hodRule.java:288)\n\tat com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)\n\tat com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)\n\tat com.sun.jersey

.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)\n\tat com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1469)\n\tat com.sun.jersey.server.impl.a

pplication.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1400)\n\tat com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1349)\n\tat com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.We

bApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1339)\n\tat com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)\n\tat com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContain

er.java:537)\n\tat com.atlassian.plugins.rest.module.RestDelegatingServletFilter$JerseyOsgiServletContainer.doFilter(RestDelegatingServletFilter.java:178)\n\tat com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.doFilter(Servle

tContainer.java:795)\n\tat com.atlassian.plugins.rest.module.RestDelegatingServletFilter.doFilter(RestDelegatingServletFilter.java:73)\n\tat com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilte

r.java:74)\n\tat com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:42)\n\tat com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.doFilter(ServletFilterModuleContainerFil

ter.java:77)\n\tat com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.doFilter(ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.java:63)\n\tat com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPlu

ginFilter.java:74)\n\tat com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:42)\n\tat com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter$1.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:66)\n

\tat com.atlassian.plugins.rest.module.servlet.RestServletUtilsUpdaterFilter.doFilterInternal(RestServletUtilsUpdaterFilter.java:26)\n\tat com.atlassian.plugins.rest.module.servlet.RestServletUtilsUpdaterFilter.doFilter(RestServle

tUtilsUpdaterFilter.java:40)\n\tat com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:74)\n\tat com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.ja

va:42)\n\tat com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter$1.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:66)\n\tat com.atlassian.applinks.core.rest.context.ContextFilter.doFilter(ContextFilter.java:25)\n\tat com.atlassian.pl

ugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:74)\n\tat com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:42)\n\tat com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.Se

rvletFilterModuleContainerFilter.doFilter(ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.java:77)\n\tat com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.doFilter(ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.java:63)\n\tat org.mort

bay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1264)\n\tat com.cenqua.fisheye.web.filters.RestFilter.doFilter(RestFilter.java:36)\n\tat com.cenqua.fisheye.web.filters.CrucibleRestFilter.doFilter(CrucibleRestFi

lter.java:21)\n\tat org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1264)\n\tat com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:46)\n\tat com.atlassian.plugin

.servlet.filter.ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.doFilter(ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.java:77)\n\tat com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.doFilter(ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.java:

63)\n\tat org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1264)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:83)\n\tat org.springframework.web.fil

ter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)\n\tat org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1264)\n\tat com.atlassian.crucible.filters.CrucibleFilter.doFilter(CrucibleFilter.ja

va:146)\n\tat org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1264)\n\tat com.cenqua.fisheye.web.filters.TotalityFilter.doFilter(TotalityFilter.java:286)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingF

ilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)\n\tat org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHan

dler.java:1264)\n\tat com.atlassian.security.auth.trustedapps.filter.TrustedApplicationsFilter.doFilter(TrustedApplicationsFilter.java:98)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterP

roxy.java:237)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)\n\tat org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1264)\n\tat com.atlassian.plugin.

servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:46)\n\tat com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter$1.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:66)\n\tat com.atlassian.oauth.serviceprovider.inter

nal.servlet.OAuthFilter.doFilter(OAuthFilter.java:71)\n\tat com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:74)\n\tat com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilte

r(IteratingFilterChain.java:42)\n\tat com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.doFilter(ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.java:77)\n\tat com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.ServletFilterModuleContain

erFilter.doFilter(ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.java:63)\n\tat org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1264)\n\tat com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(Iteratin

gFilterChain.java:46)\n\tat com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.doFilter(ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.java:77)\n\tat com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.d

oFilter(ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.java:63)\n\tat org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1264)\n\tat org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:399)\n\tat org.m

ortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)\n\tat org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)\n\tat org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:766)\n

\tat org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:450)\n\tat org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:327)\n\tat org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:126)\n\tat com.c

enqua.fisheye.web.filters.TotalityFilter.doFilter(TotalityFilter.java:187)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFi

lterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)\n\tat org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1264)\n\tat com.atlassian.security.auth.trustedapps.filter.TrustedApplicationsFilter.doFilter(Tru

stedApplicationsFilter.java:98)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.ja

va:167)\n\tat org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1264)\n\tat com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:46)\n\tat com.atlassian.plugin.servl

et.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter$1.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:66)\n\tat com.atlassian.oauth.serviceprovider.internal.servlet.OAuthFilter.doFilter(OAuthFilter.java:71)\n\tat com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingP

luginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:74)\n\tat com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:42)\n\tat com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.ServletFilterModuleContainerFilte

r.doFilter(ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.java:77)\n\tat com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.doFilter(ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.java:63)\n\tat org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandle

r$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1264)\n\tat org.mortbay.servlet.UserAgentFilter.doFilter(UserAgentFilter.java:78)\n\tat org.mortbay.servlet.GzipFilter.doFilter(GzipFilter.java:154)\n\tat com.cenqua.fisheye.web.filters.CustomI

ncludableGzipFilter.doFilter(CustomIncludableGzipFilter.java:27)\n\tat org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1264)\n\tat com.cenqua.fisheye.web.filters.ProductInfoFilter.doFilter(ProductInfoFi

lter.java:44)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)\n\tat org.

mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1264)\n\tat com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:46)\n\tat com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.ServletF

ilterModuleContainerFilter.doFilter(ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.java:77)\n\tat com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.doFilter(ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.java:63)\n\tat org.mortbay.je

tty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1264)\n\tat com.cenqua.fisheye.web.filters.UpfrontFilter.doFilter(UpfrontFilter.java:54)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(Deleg

atingFilterProxy.java:237)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)\n\tat org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1264)\n\tat com.atlas

sian.fecru.profiling.ProfilingServletFilter.doFilter(ProfilingServletFilter.java:74)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.De

legatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)\n\tat org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1264)\n\tat org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:399)\n\

tat org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)\n\tat org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)\n\tat org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.ja

va:766)\n\tat org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:450)\n\tat org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:230)\n\tat org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollecti

on.handle(HandlerCollection.java:114)\n\tat org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)\n\tat org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)\n\tat org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpC

onnection.java:542)\n\tat org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:945)\n\tat org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:756)\n\tat org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpPar

ser.java:218)\n\tat org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)\n\tat org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:410)\n\tat org.mortbay.thread.BoundedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(Boun

dedThreadPool.java:451)\nCaused by: com.sun.jersey.api.MessageException: A message body reader for Java class com.atlassian.fecrurestplugin.crucible.RestReviewService$CreateReview, and Java type class com.atlassian.fecrurestplugin

.crucible.RestReviewService$CreateReview, and MIME media type application/octet-stream was not found.\nThe registered message body readers compatible with the MIME media type are:\n*/* ->\n com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entit

y.FormProvider\n com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StringProvider\n com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ByteArrayProvider\n com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FileProvider\n com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.

entity.InputStreamProvider\n com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DataSourceProvider\n com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLJAXBElementProvider$General\n com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ReaderProvider\n com

.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DocumentProvider\n com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$StreamSourceReader\n com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$SAXSourceReader\n com.sun.jersey.core

.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$DOMSourceReader\n com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONJAXBElementProvider$General\n com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootElementProvider$General\n com.sun.jersey.core.imp

l.provider.entity.XMLListElementProvider$General\n com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootObjectProvider$General\n com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.EntityHolderReader\n com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.

JSONRootElementProvider$General\n com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONListElementProvider$General\n com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JacksonProviderProxy\napplication/octet-stream ->\n com.sun.jersey.core.impl.

provider.entity.ByteArrayProvider\n com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FileProvider\n com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.InputStreamProvider\n com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DataSourceProvider\n com.sun.j

ersey.core.impl.provider.entity.RenderedImageProvider\n\n\t... 128 more\n"

}

after sending open review request

None 500 Internal Server Error

Answer (score 0):

The key part of the error was "MIME media type application/octet-stream"
I had to set the content type for the post
**Content-Type: application/json**
Not just the Accept header.

The issue is resolved